# REST API endpoint - weird path parameter

Tags: http, rest, curl, state

I am learning REST API and URI design and I have found one here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JeanVEGA/MI-MPR-DIP-Admission/master/examples/requests.sh

I have a few questions.

There is for example:

## User.resetPassword, anonymous by User's {email}

```
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:9090/admission/services/user/person/email:{email}/reset_password
```

I do not understand construction `email:{email}`... what does it mean? It means that if I have String path param, I need to do it in this way?

The similar is here:

## Term.get

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-CTU-FIT-Admission-Session: [session identifier from User.identity]" http://localhost:9090/admission/services/term/dateOfTerm:{dateOfTerm}/room:{room}
```

`room:{room}` - Is this because room should be for example 123ABC? So it is not a number so it need to be written in this way?

And my last question:

## User.resetPassword for User by Admission Code, send notification to User's Email and this {email}

```
curl -i -H "X-CTU-FIT-Admission-Session: [session identifier from User.identity]" -X POST http://localhost:9090/admission/services/user/admission/{admissionCode}/person/email:{email}/reset_password
```

My poiont of question is "`reset_password`" ... I thought due to right design principles that no verb should be in URI... because if the verb is in URI, I thought that it means that resource is actually an operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That url can be only a resource identifier. So this is an [url template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) which waits a unique email address as a parameter. A filled in template should look something like this:

```
./person/email:my@email.adr/reset_password
```

*note:*

The `reset_password` is not a valid REST resource (it describes a service not a resource) and the `POST` method is [mostly for resource creation](http://jasonsirota.com/rest-partial-updates-use-post-put-or-patch) (not for update or partial update). Real REST requests look like this:

```
PUT ./person/email:{email}/password "newpass"
PUT ./person/{id}/password "newpass"
PUT ./person/email:{email}/identification_factors/password "newpass"
PATCH ./person/email:{email}/identification_factors {password: "newpass"}
```

and so on...

Comment: Can I ask to my usecase? I have one system which manages an evolution of few algorithms in collection. I designed my endpoints in this way:

For detection which algorithm from collection is the best:
/collection/{collection-id}/tasks/best (GET)

For update that some algorithm was chosen:
/collection/{collection-id}/tasks/selection/algorithms/{algorithm-id}

And to send feedback to algorithm:
/collection/{collection-id}/tasks/feedback/algorithms/{algorithm-id}

Is this the right design? Or there are not a valid REST resources? (I mean "best", "selection", "feedback"?)

Comment: I think it is better to put the mapreduce part into the queryString (except by the unique ids). So `/collection/{collection-id}/tasks?best=true` or `/collection/{collection-id}/tasks?filter="best:true"`, etc... I am not sure about the others... By `a:b = 1:n` relations: `/a/bs/{b-id}`, by `a:b = 1:1` relations: `/a/b`, by `a:b = n:m` relations: `/a/{a-id}`, `/b/{b-id}`, `/ab/{ab-id}/a` and `/ab/{ab-id}/b` the valid url. Anything else, like which is the best, which is earlier than a timestamp, ... should go the queryString because it's about the current query, not about the resource structure.